# What is this type of (speech bubble text) style called?

Tags: typography, text, terminology

Where the text fills every part of the bubble.

I know this is most likely a (custom) font stretched and warped to fit in the box. I also know that there's most likely no one easy way to do it.

What I would like to know:

- What the style is called?
- How *you* would handle doing something like this (in the fastest/most efficient way possible - which program to use, AI or PS).

I'm not necessarily talking about the flame, just in general where the text is stretched to fill the whole bubble.

<sub><sup>**Maybe this has to be hand drawn?**</sup></sub>

---

[image]

Comment: Not every kind of graphic has a name.  It's just a speech bubble, shaped like a flame. It's a bit weird if I'm honest, or should I say unique. @Vincent has given you a tutorial!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My first guess would be to hand draw this, but you might have some success using an *envelope distort* in Illustrator.

1. Type and layout your text;
2. Convert to outlines: <kbd>Type</kbd> > <kbd>Create Outlines</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>;
3. Ungroup all text objects: <kbd>Object</kbd> > <kbd>Ungroup</kbd>, multiple times until no groups remain;
4. Select all text objects and make them into one compound path: <kbd>Object</kbd> > <kbd>Compound Path</kbd> > <kbd>Make</kbd>;
5. Create a version of your speech bubble with the tiny details removed. In the above example, a flame shape made with 4-6 anchors should suffice;
6. Have the simplified bubble shape sit above the text compound path in the Layer order and remove its outline and fill colours;
7. Select both the simplified bubble shape and the text compound path and choose <kbd>Object</kbd> > <kbd>Envelope Distort</kbd> > <kbd>Make With Top Object</kbd>

If your success is limited, making an envelope distort with a Mesh rather than a template object might also work. It's really a case-by-case thing.